# How do i append records to a view without dropping and recreating the table in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a view that I am creating in BigQuery.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ... { ... }
```

I need to set it so that everyday new records are Appended to the view. Instead of The view being dropped and then fully recreated everyday.

Any ideas on how to go about doing this.

Comment: Views store a query not data.  You need to put the data into a table if you want to store it.

Comment: @NoStressZone Is comment provided by Gordon helpful for you? As he mentioned, data need to be stored in a table.